# LaTeX memoir and header-footer positions

Tags: header-footer, memoir

Does anyone know how to get the headers and footers in a memoir document to align with the upper and lower margins? The only formatting issue I have with the graduate school is the following:

"The line below the page number indicates the footer and not the margin requirement. You should bring the footer up so that it aligns with the margins.  The CHAPTER and Page headers should be removed from the header section and placed in the main text."

To the best of my knowledge, if I can get the headers and footers to start at the upper and lower margin lines, that should remedy the issue but have no clue of how to go about doing this (and the LaTeX style they linked me to (a) doesn't work and is unreadable so I've had to write my own) which is linked to here: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/gDhCYKaS).

Even a suggestion of where to begin looking will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this only means upper and lower margins are calculated w.r.t. the header and footer, not w.r.t. the body of your document.

Comment: Not from what I can tell. It appears that everything has to be within the bounds of the margins including header and footer information.

Comment: You should probably rephrase your question as it us not particularly clear what you are asking for. And please don't provide data external to the site, used are your question with what ever is in that paste in link. In memoir the upper and lower margins are in related to the text body. The headers live inside that space.